# Bootstrap accordion Javascript to open one card when the other closes

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have a standard Bootstrap accordion and I don't want the option to have all cards closed at the same time, I have two total.

Right now... If I click on one, it opens and if I click on it again it closes. The first card starts open and I want it to automatically open the second one if I close the first and vice versa. This way one will always be open.

Here is my code, I appreciate your help.

```html
    <div id="accordion">
       <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
             <h5 class="mb-0">
               <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" 
                       aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
               Collapsible Group Item #1
               </button>
            </h5>
         </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```js
    I was trying to do something like this...
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
              $('#collapseOne').on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
                $('#collapseTwo').collapse('show')
                }); 
            });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `click` event on `button-link` . So , whenever your button is clicked check if it has `collapsed` class or not depending on this get `data-target` of another button and show that div using `collapse('show')`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(".btn-link").on("click", function() {
  //check if the button not have class collapsed
  if (!$(this).hasClass("collapsed")) {
    //get another button data-target and show that(use .first() if needed has more then 2 button)
    console.log($(".btn-link").not(this).data('target'))
    $($(".btn-link").not(this).data('target')).collapse('show')
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
               Collapsible Group Item #1
               </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        u probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Weird.. I see that it works in the snippet but I can't get it to work at all in my Django template. I have all the links and scripts installed, code exactly the same.

Comment: Any error inside console ? Also , do `console.log($(".btn-link").not(this).data('target'))` see if its giving you correct id or not .

Comment: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `$(".btn-link").not'

Comment: on which line are you getting that error  in code itself or `console.log($(".btn-link").not(this).data('target'))` ?

Comment: on console.log($(".btn-link").not(this).data('target'))

Comment: You can see updated code i am not seeing that error i did console ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231854/discussion-between-swati-and-ryan-thomas).